# How can I list all resources that belongs to a certain VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

At my AWS account, I have few VPC. I'm trying to find a way to list all resources that located under a certain VPC.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can stored by looking at the Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs), since that is how resources connect to a VPC (eg Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS). Is there a particular reason for wanting to list these resources? (Please let us know more details and we can probably give you a better answer.)

Comment: well, under my account there are several VPC, under each many resources. I find it very hard to manage all those resources. as a first step to remedy this clutter, I've decided to manually map my resources and verify if there is something can be done in order to save costs.

Answer (score 33):

You can do it in three ways: AWS CLI, AWS console or code.

### **AWS CLI**

---

You can use AWS CLI to list all ENIs associated with the VPC and prettify the output using the `--query` parameter to get a resource list with the desired fields (AZ, instance-id, etc.).

1. ```
   aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=<vpc-id> --query  'NetworkInterfaces[*].[AvailabilityZone, OwnerId, Attachment.InstanceId, PrivateIpAddresses[*].Association.PublicIp]'
   ```
2. ```
   aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=<vpc-id> --query  'NetworkInterfaces[*].[RequesterId,Description]'
   ```

   A sample of the raw output (only one instance on the VPC):

   ```
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
            "Association": {
                "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                "PublicDnsName": "ec2-54-196-57-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                "PublicIp": "54.196.57.169"
            },
            "Attachment": {
                "AttachTime": "2020-08-24T10:59:16+00:00",
                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-047e562690aabbffd",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                "InstanceId": "i-0fe495a6c17bd0f82",
                "InstanceOwnerId": "570398916848",
                "Status": "attached"
            },
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1d",
            "Description": "",
            "Groups": [
                {
                    "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1",
                    "GroupId": "sg-0aa7d8257bb487e1b"
                }
            ],
            "InterfaceType": "interface",
            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
            "MacAddress": "0e:58:38:33:9a:31",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0b20855178d276783",
            "OwnerId": "570398916848",
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-34-30.ec2.internal",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.34.30",
            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                {
                    "Association": {
                        "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-54-196-57-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                        "PublicIp": "54.196.57.169"
                    },
                    "Primary": true,
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-34-30.ec2.internal",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.34.30"
                }
            ],
            "RequesterManaged": false,
            "SourceDestCheck": true,
            "Status": "in-use",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-e2bc5fbd",
            "TagSet": [],
            "VpcId": "vpc-6ad2e110"
        }
    ]
   ```

And now filtered:

1. For the first `--query`

   ```
    [
        "us-east-1d",
        "57039816848",
        "i-0fe495a6c17bd0f82",
        [
            "44.196.57.169"
        ]
    ]
   ```
2. And for the second `--query` (another VPC):

   ```
    [
        "amazon-elasticache",
        "ElastiCache alon-001"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elasticache",
        "ElastiCache alon-002"
    ],
    [
        "975289786086",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:57039916848:attachment/22a90802-fae7-4afb-9a7e-43e6f4be8ca4"
    ],
    [
        "074689309192",
        "Interface for NAT Gateway nat-069344579d8bda20"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elb",
        "ELB app/EC2Co-EcsEl-YX74WCWEGOK/0b6d7bc60b540b1"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elb",
        "ELB app/EC2Co-EcsEl-YX74WCWGGOK/0b6bd7c60b540b1"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elasticache",
        "ElastiCache alon-003"
    ]
   ```

### **AWS Console**

---

You can do the same using the AWS console.
Under EC2->Network Interfaces, search for the desired `vpc-id` in the search bar.
[image]

### Code

---

Using a python script called [vpc-inside.py](https://gist.github.com/alonlavian/4f10ccb37aed9c20b208ae24e9f6ad2a) you can describe all of your VPC resources.

```
usage: vpc-inside.py [-h] -v VPC [-r REGION] [-p PROFILE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                     show this help message and exit
  -v VPC, --vpc VPC              The VPC to annihilate
  -r REGION, --region REGION     AWS region that the VPC resides in
  -p PROFILE, --profile PROFILE  AWS profile
```

And the output will look like this:

```
EKSs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
Omikron
--------------------------------------------
ASGs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
eks-pooks-9ebf225b-70a9-a026-034f-c7431df9b7ba resides in vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82
eks-pooks-9ebf225b-70a9-a026-034f-c7431df9b7ba
--------------------------------------------
RDSs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
--------------------------------------------
EC2s in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
i-0c63874d77ea2ba78
i-043740f224015e69e
--------------------------------------------
Lambdas in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
--------------------------------------------
Classic ELBs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
--------------------------------------------
ELBs V2 in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
--------------------------------------------
NAT GWs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
--------------------------------------------
VPC EndPoints in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
--------------------------------------------
IGWs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
--------------------------------------------
ENIs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
eni-079231232dc136305
eni-05ff227eca8341a08
eni-0c01b2871887ac3f7
eni-00e11d4f9590161b4
--------------------------------------------
Security Groups in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
sg-0b4554a65e1560745
sg-0f93574d6b180b263
--------------------------------------------
Routing tables in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
rtb-0694bdbdd696b2bed
rtb-072ec82a18d8a04ba
--------------------------------------------
ACLs in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
acl-0c0087eabf9335940
--------------------------------------------
Subnets in VPC vpc-07ef7f777429cfd82:
subnet-0b8cc1132727e5b5d
subnet-0e47ee92a9ca80280
subnet-0c25990d9a138616b
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 16):

You can try in AWS Config > Advanced queries and run below query :

**All resources:**
SELECT
resourceId,
resourceName,
resourceType

***Resources directly associated to VPC:***
SELECT
resourceId,
resourceName,
resourceType
WHERE
relationships.resourceId = 'vpc-02368dae78f1387e5'

Query can be further enhanced, see some example of preconfigured query.

Comment: This was very helpful and very quickly allowed me to track down a bunch of orphaned stuff I had created while learning.

Comment: Important: To use AWS Config Advanced Queries you must first go to AWS Config -> Settings, and then Edit to turn on recording.  It may have you set up an S3 bucket etc...

Answer (score 8):

VPCs mostly contain EC2 instances, RDS instances, Load Balancers and Lambda functions. Plus, things that use EC2 underneath, like Elasticache. These are the types of resources that connect into a VPC.

Some people suggest using the Tag Editor to find resources: [Is there a way to list all resources in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616664/174777).

I also like [aws inventory](https://github.com/devops-israel/aws-inventory), which simply runs in your browser and does a great job of showing resources. Just give it an Access Key and Secret Key to run.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in service to easily do this.

The best hope you'd have of find all resources is programatically looping over resources that support:

- SubnetId
- VpcId