# Which AWS resources can be attached / related to a specific VPC? (to verify it's safe to delete it)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm looking for a way to understand if we are making use of a specific VPC

The easy way is to review resources 1-by-1 like:

1. EC2 Machines
2. RDS
3. Client-VPN-Endpoint
4. Other resources - What else do I need to check?

And check manually.
is there another way to determine what is relying on a specific VPC before I'll delete it?

Comment: You can generate VPC Flow logs and check what traffic is happening in your VPC. Have you considered that?

Comment: Will try, good idea.

Comment: In addition to performing aws cloud watch logs insight query for your VPC  flowlogs. Your can also have a look at [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-dependency-error-delete-vpc/) from aws.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997608/how-can-i-list-all-resources-that-belongs-to-a-certain-vpc/64280537#64280537

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways: AWS CLI or AWS console.

**AWS CLI**

You can use AWS CLI to list all ENIs associated with the VPC and prettify the output using the `--query` parameter to get a resource list with the desired fields (AZ, instance-id, etc.).

1. ```
     `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=<vpc-id> --query  'NetworkInterfaces[*].[AvailabilityZone, OwnerId, Attachment.InstanceId, PrivateIpAddresses[*].Association.PublicIp]'
   ```
2. ```
     `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=<vpc-id> --query  'NetworkInterfaces[*].[RequesterId,Description]'
   ```

   A sample of the raw output (only one instance on the VPC):

   ```
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
            "Association": {
                "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                "PublicDnsName": "ec2-54-196-57-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                "PublicIp": "54.196.57.169"
            },
            "Attachment": {
                "AttachTime": "2020-08-24T10:59:16+00:00",
                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-047e562690aabbffd",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                "InstanceId": "i-0fe495a6c17bd0f82",
                "InstanceOwnerId": "570398916848",
                "Status": "attached"
            },
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1d",
            "Description": "",
            "Groups": [
                {
                    "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1",
                    "GroupId": "sg-0aa7d8257bb487e1b"
                }
            ],
            "InterfaceType": "interface",
            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
            "MacAddress": "0e:58:38:33:9a:31",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0b20855178d276783",
            "OwnerId": "570398916848",
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-34-30.ec2.internal",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.34.30",
            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                {
                    "Association": {
                        "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-54-196-57-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
                        "PublicIp": "54.196.57.169"
                    },
                    "Primary": true,
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-34-30.ec2.internal",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.34.30"
                }
            ],
            "RequesterManaged": false,
            "SourceDestCheck": true,
            "Status": "in-use",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-e2bc5fbd",
            "TagSet": [],
            "VpcId": "vpc-6ad2e110"
        }
    ]
   ```

And now filtered:

1. For the first `--query`

   ```
    [
        "us-east-1d",
        "57039816848",
        "i-0fe495a6c17bd0f82",
        [
            "44.196.57.169"
        ]
    ]
   ```
2. And for the second `--query` (another VPC):

   ```
    [
        "amazon-elasticache",
        "ElastiCache alon-001"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elasticache",
        "ElastiCache alon-002"
    ],
    [
        "975289786086",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:57039916848:attachment/22a90802-fae7-4afb-9a7e-43e6f4be8ca4"
    ],
    [
        "074689309192",
        "Interface for NAT Gateway nat-069344579d8bda20"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elb",
        "ELB app/EC2Co-EcsEl-YX74WCWEGOK/0b6d7bc60b540b1"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elb",
        "ELB app/EC2Co-EcsEl-YX74WCWGGOK/0b6bd7c60b540b1"
    ],
    [
        "amazon-elasticache",
        "ElastiCache alon-003"
    ]
   ```

**AWS Console**

You can do the same using the AWS console.
Under EC2->Network Interfaces, search for the desired `vpc-id` in the search bar.
[image]